# Simple PHP/mySQL query?

Tags: php, mysql, html, sql, forms

I have a database that stores the users name, number, and carrier in a table called `user`.

I need to know how to write a query that if my value is equal to `name` - it will fetch the number and carrier associated with that name. I am writing this in php and will use javascript if necessary.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please post the query you've tried, because what you ask is frankly an extremely basic SQL query involving a WHERE clause.

Comment: What is your table structure ? And what have you tried till now ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I should prefer you to use "SELECT * FROM user WHERE name LIKE '{$value}'"
because using = will search for the exact value
For example: if in database the value is john and u searched for John it will not display the result but if you use LIKE it will display all the related results like JOHN, john, John, jOHN etc.

Thanking You,
Megha

Answer (score 1):

You can just put one of the following:

1)

```
$value = "John";
$result = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM user WHERE name LIKE '$value'" );
```

above query will return rows matching name like JOHN, john, John,etc as suggested by Megha.

2)

```
$value = "John";
$result = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM user WHERE name='$value'" );
```

above query will return rows matching name with the value 'John'.

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL query will look like this:

```
"SELECT * FROM user WHERE name = '{$value}'"
```

This selects all columns in the table `user` where the `name` column has a value of the PHP variable `$value`

You can execute this query using PHP's MySQL functions: http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php

**Example**

```
$value = "John";
$result = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM user WHERE name = '{$value}'" );

while( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result ) )
     print( "Column with name columnName has a value of " . $row['columnName'] );
```

Comment: -1 for not at least mentioning the danger of SQL injection when building a SQL string like you describe. Also, I think you posted the wrong link.

Comment: Edited fixing the link, and if I gave a tutorial on everything a database application developer needed to know on security (SQL Injection, Directory Traversal, HTML injection, XSS, etc.) then each answer would be so complex that the asker most likely wouldn't understand it.

Comment: Mentioning escaping would hardly make your answer overly complex.

Comment: You're making the assumption he's even taking user input. Perhaps the name is hard coded in the application? Perhaps he already has sanitized the values but doesn't know the MySQL query? Perhaps he's used MSSQL before? To go into why he should sanitize not only makes assumptions about the OP's prior knowledge but also distracts from the question they're asking and further complicates the situation. It's Technical Support 101 to address one problem at a time.

Comment: What if the value is hardcoded? It could contain a dangerous typo. What about is he's use MSSQL before? It's hardly immune to SQL-injection. And I don't disagree with addressing a single problem at a time, but in my opinion it's the same problem. If you want to insert variable values into SQL, you need to know how you do it safely.